# Returning statuses from MGTwitterEngine

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mgtwitterengine

I am using MGTwitterEngine in an iPhone application to make a simple call for user statuses. The engine has a delegate method:

```
- (void)statusesReceived:(NSArray *)statuses forRequest:(NSString *)identifier
```

And I can see my statuses logged in the console. My question is what is the best way to then use the statuses and be informed when they have been received?

I suspect this might be more about how to use the delegate pattern properly.

Thanks,

Comment: I have partially solved this using NSNotifications.

 NSNotification* notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"tweetsArrived" object:self];

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with setting up an NSNotification observer and then calling that from statusesReceived:forRequest. I also set an NSArray iVar in the delegate method which I access in my NSNotification callback:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tweetNotificationHandler:) name:@"tweetsArrived" object:nil]; 

- (void)statusesReceived:(NSArray *)statuses forRequest:(NSString *)identifier{

tweets = statuses; //this is an ivar

NSNotification* notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"tweetsArrived" object:self];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];

}

-(void)tweetNotificationHandler: (NSNotification*)notification   {
//do your results handling here.
}
```